# Add additional content to the custom user Control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a custom user control which contains ToolBar with buttons. I want these buttons and toolbar to be the base content of the control and assign it to different views. But for some views, in some cases, I need to add additional tools to the toolbar, or additional toolbar itself at the end of the already existing ones.
I tried control template and dependency property binding. In control template case I must move my already existing buttons from Content to template and that makes my buttons inaccessible from the code behind (I need to expose these buttons with public properties for other views to add event handlers on them later because different views need to have different responses on the same events).
As for the dependency property and ContentPresenter, well it just did not work and I have no idea why.

here is my XAML for UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Syllogia.Desktop.Controls.SylToolBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Syllogia.Desktop.Controls"
         xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="150">


<Grid>
    <telerik:RadToolBar Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MainToolBar" AutoHideOverflowButton="True">
        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="AddButton">
            <Image Source="icons/Pixel/plus_math_30px.png"/>
        </telerik:RadButton>

        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="EditButton">
            <Image x:Name="ToggleButtonImage" Source="icons/Pixel/edit_32px.png"/>
        </telerik:RadButton>

        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="DeleteButton">
            <Image Source="icons/Pixel/erase.png"/>
        </telerik:RadButton>

        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="PrintButton">
            <Image Source="icons/Pixel/print_30px.png"/>
        </telerik:RadButton>

        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="RefreshButton">
            <Image Source="icons/Pixel/refresh_32px.png"/>
        </telerik:RadButton>

        <Grid x:Name="GridAdditionalContent">

        </Grid>

    </telerik:RadToolBar>
</Grid>
```

question 1: Is there another way to add additional content to this control from the other controls?
question 2: Is there a way to expose buttons which are declared inside a template?
I am fairly new to WPF and there may be some detail which I was not able to search and find.
In any case, Thank you for your help and sorry if I am asking stupid questions here.

Comment: There is another way of adding content to your control, which would be from code. Are you familiar with the MVVM pattern? You could give your UserControl it's own VM and handle Button creation from there. You could make your own VM for a RadButton which has Properties like Content and create these VMs in your UserControls VM. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with MVVM, though I am using viewmodels only for Data objects, like making one property in a VM which is then assigned to a gridview or treelistview, I do not know any further functions and use cases for VM. Could you provide a resource for me to learn more? Thanks for your help, I will try to search more about MVVM meanwhile.